# Difference between HttpRequestDefaults and HttpRequest in Jmeter Load Testing

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for Load Testing. In Jmeter i am creating Scenario for load test.
There is two option available as given below-

ThreadGroup -> ConfigElement -> **HttprequestDefaults**

and

ThreadGroup -> Sampler -> **Httprequest**.

I want to know that what is difference between these two options(HttprequestDefaults and Httprequest) while creating scenario.

Answer (score 2):

`HttprequestDefaults` sets the default values for the `Httprequest` controllers in the test plan. So the actual HTTP request is peformed by `Httprequest` sampler and `HttprequestDefaults` configures HTTP request samplers as implied by its control type `ConfigElement`.

Answer (score 2):

HttprequestDefaults and Httprequest works on concept of Global and Local Variable

If you set any values in HttprequestDefaults, It will apply on all httprequest
For Example: Domain Name, Proxy server Name, Protocol etc. ; You don't need to go one by one in all the httprequest to do that

And if, In a scenario any httprequest values is different than httprequestdefaults (Global Variable) ; It will take httprequest values in scenario run (Local Variable) (Priority)

Hope this helps !